# SVN Post-Commit Hook Fail (exit code 1) with output:

Tags: svn, version-control, visualsvn-server

I'm new to using hooks for **SVN**. Basically i'm new to setting up an SVN repository and everything.
Basically what I am trying to do here is copy whatever is committed to the repository to my existing live site.

I am using VisualSVN. This is my **post-commit** hook code or somewhat of a code.
`"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\svn.exe" export mysvnurl D:\myfolder\websitefolder --quiet --non-interactive --force --username ***** --password *****`

And i get this error everytime I commit a file.

```
Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:  
Error: svn: E730061: Unable to connect to a repository at URL mysvnurl
Error: svn: E730061: Error running context: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve the error? I am not sure if inputted the write post-commit command, since i just found it using google.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

means that the URL is incorrect. Check that you specify the correct port and protocol (https vs http) in the URL.

Comment: Hi bahrep, thanks for the reply.
Actually i tried both https and http. I still get the same error.
Is there any other way? I read about using svnsync to mirror the files to a certain folder. Is it use as the same way like what I am doing?

Comment: @JohnPaulPo it's not only about the protocol; check the port number.

Comment: Hi bahrep, thanks for the help. Do you have any idea how to disable the ssl checking for VisualSVN? I always get an error.

post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
svn: E230001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://***/svn/SoulSeekDev'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted

Comment: * `--non-interactive` See http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.non_interactive

* `--trust-server-cert` See http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.trust_server_cert

Comment: Hi bahrep, thanks so much for the help. I hope i can make this work. I am such a newbie at setting up svn.

Comment: i've updated the code to check and export only those files that have been added or updated.

but i get this error:
Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with output:  
Error: Access is denied.  

I've checked the urls, username and passwords. They all match.
I've also check the access rights and read/write they are all okay.

Comment: found the cause for the access denied. It when i use the svnlook, that causes the access denied.